# Can ForkJoin be Used With Multiple NGRX Store Values?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

`Angular 7` `RXJS 6.3` `NGRX 6.1.2`

My Angular application comprises several lazy loaded modules. When one of these lazy loaded modules loads, the root component `NgOnInit` obtains the Window width and height and calls an NGRX Action to save the values in the `Store`. Additionally there are some other global constants which are already in the `Store`.

I tried to use an RXJS `ForkJoin` to gather all of these values from the `Store` and once they have all been obtained call a function to perform a calculation using them, but I couldn't get it to work. I thought I would be able to define an array of `Observables` using  `.first()` and pass this in.

I would be very grateful if someone could suggest how you `subscribe` to multiple values in the `Store` and once they have all been obtained call a function.

Comment: Can you show what exactly did you try? Code helps. Stackblitz would help even more.

Comment: It's hard to give any advice without any code. I guess maybe one or more source Observables passed to `forkJoin` don't complete...

Comment: I'll try and write it again to show you my approach (I deleted it after I couldn't make it work). Back soon.

Comment: For multiple selections, its preferable to use combineLatest() instead of forkJoin().

Comment: The more I read, the more I tend to agree, `combineLatest()` does seem the way to go. Thank you.